# Correct way to register service with discovery server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix

I'm trying the first time to create an API with micro services.
For this I'm using Java with Spring and the Netflix stack.
What I have problems with is to register a service to the discovery server (which works fine).

Discovery Server:

java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.SpringCloudApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringCloudApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "heiseTut/registerApplication");
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

yml for the discovery-Server:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself!!!!!!!!!!!!
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

Service which I want to register:

java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
public class HelloServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "heiseTut/helloApplication");
        SpringApplication.run(HelloServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

yml for this service:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/
 
server:
    port: 8888
```

bootstrap for this service:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: helloWorld-service
```

Part of the error message (very long so I only include the, hopefully correct, important parts:

```
2017-03-31 12:12:39.258  WARN 228 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Action: Refresh  => returned status of 401 from http://localhost:1111/eureka/apps/
2017-03-31 12:12:39.260 ERROR 228 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://localhost:1111/eureka/apps/
Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?

java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad status: 401
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1155)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:835)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:746)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:320)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:197)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:193)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryManager.initComponent(DiscoveryManager.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.DiscoveryManagerInitializer.init(DiscoveryManagerInitializer.java:39)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.start(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at heiseTut.helloService.HelloServiceApplication.main(HelloServiceApplication.java:17)

2017-03-31 12:12:39.260 ERROR 228 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_BOOTSTRAP/DESKTOP-S716PSE - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Bad status: 401

.
. other error messages
.

2017-03-31 12:12:39.356  INFO 228 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2bbaf4f0: startup date [Fri Mar 31 12:12:36 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at heiseTut.helloService.HelloServiceApplication.main(HelloServiceApplication.java:17)
```

Thanks for possible help and replies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution.
At least in a devlopment environment you can turn off the security in the application.yml of the discovery server:

```
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: You must have spring-security on the classpath of the Eureka server.  Is there a reason why you want to secure your Eureka server?  I think you want at least want the Eureka server endpoints open.

Comment: You can also supply the username and password in the eureka url in the client.